# how do I say if a cell has any color then?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up a macro to fill in any gaps of colour in my tick off sheet after new data is entered.
I have a colour for each day of the working week i.e. Monday through Friday. this sometimes leaves gaps when the days info is imported into the list, because of the different colours I wanted to avoid having to do 5 different lines of code (one for each day) so instead of referencing the colour index of each day I am wondering is there a way to say if interior.colorindex = anything except from xlnone then.

fyi I am a self taught beginner.

this is my current code

```
For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BG9:BG500")
If Range("BG" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 26 Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL
```

and this works for that colour in that cell however I am already going to have to write this out 10x per category and there are 6 categories so I would like to avoid having to write this out a further 5 times (1 for each colour.
I tried adding an or 5 times (1 for each colour) but it ended up forgetting the firs part of the and I am assuming to fix this I would have to write the first part out every time but this just seems extremely bulky and tedious and I have to assume there is an easier way to do it.

[data pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsECD.png)

this picture shows the sheet I am working on. it shows the newly inputted data at the bottom (three pink cells) above it are the gaps.
the gaps all need to be the same colour as the three pink cells. I am trying to set up some code that I can run regardless of what colour day it is and how many boxes need filling in I can just run it and it fill in the gaps.

the gaps in the data are un avoidable unfortunately as the line only reports what run they are finishing on. Each row is responsible for its own run number. I have a table on the spreadsheet that takes the qty completed through any given section (in this case the section is out) then express that quantity as a percentage of the run and then colours in cells based on that percentage each cell is worth 10%. I then transfer that data to the sheet based on another bit of code but obviously if the line has completed full runs that day there will be gaps in the tick off sheet. therefore, in this example I am trying to say if BG15 is coloured then BG14 (if it is blank) needs to be the same colour as BG15 I thought if I could get it working for 1 cell first I could then apply that to all of the other cells that need updating as well.

an obviously the colour wont always be 26 as my colours are
monday=44 tuesday=3 wednesday=26 thursday=28 friday=27

so any help or guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

so I think vie figured out a way to achieve what I want this is my current code, I'm not sure how to proceed with this. the part that helped me that I was originally asking about was solved by a comment made by @FaneDuru but I can no longer find the comment, so should I answer it myself whit the below code or should I select FaneDuru's answer, if a mod sees this can they let me know the proper procedure, thanks.

```
Sub FILLGAPS()

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BP9:BP500")
If Range("BP" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BO9:BO500")
If Range("BO" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BN9:BN500")
If Range("BN" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BM9:BM500")
If Range("BM" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BL9:BL500")
If Range("BL" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BK9:BK500")
If Range("BK" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BJ9:BJ500")
If Range("BJ" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BI9:BI500")
If Range("BI" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BH9:BH500")
If Range("BH" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BG9:BG500")
If Range("BG" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Range("BG9" & CELL.ROW)` be `Range("BG18")` if the Cell is on the 9th row? Probably a typo there. You can normally check the weekday of a date and use an array with the stored indexes to assign them that way if that's what you're after. Or Have an array with the indexes and give the current cell the next color if it has none. They are ordered chronologically and without duplicated days, right?

Comment: hi, if that is the way to write that then I think that will answer my question I will give it a test and let you know if it works, thankyou

Comment: hi Notus_panda I see the error I think, that shouldn't say BG9 it should just say BG as this is meant to loop through all of the cells in BG, thanks for bringing my attention to that

Comment: hi @FaneDuru I have tried entering <>xlnone but it comes up with a compile error expected:expression I will try and edit my question with some more info

Comment: Will the next row always be the same color you'd want in the row you're checking if it's "empty"? If so, you can check if it's empty with `If CELL.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then` and fill the cell's color with `CELL.Interior.Color= CELL.Offset(1).Interior.Color`

Comment: This only means that you wrongly wrote the code line. Please, test the code I pasted, **as it is** and only after seeing it working you may try adapting according to your needs. Of course, you should color some cells in the respective range to be processed...

Comment: I have an additional question: what if row 15 in your example would be uncolored as well?

Comment: then I am hoping nothing would happen, as that means that all of the current data is up to date with no gaps, the gaps will only appear when new data is inputted into the sheet and yes whaterver the colour is in the bg column is the colour that needs to fill in the gaps as that production was completed all on the same day (I hope this makes sense) @notus_Panda

Comment: What does te manually written numbers mean?  I mean, 9 to 15. I carefully read what you wrote after you edited the answer, but I must confess that I do not understand what is it to be done. How the code will `know` that "production was completed all on the same day"? To make the code fill the gaps with the below them cell it is extremely simple... I will adapt my code to do it, but please, try clarifying the above question.

Comment: I adapted my answer code to fill the gaps with the color of the cell bellow it. Take care that I modified the range, it starts from the second row. Otherwise, there is no  `Cell.Offset(-1)` for the first row...

Comment: @FaneDuru the manually written numbers are the cells so the data starts at cell 9 and the idea is I import the figures for the day and it pastes in the colour into the cells. and in some cases it will leave gaps these gaps must have been completed on the same day as the most recent input and therefore must be the same colour the idea behind my thinking is that if a cell in the BG column is coloured any blanks before it need to be coloured in in the same colour and i will have a look at the answer you posted, sorry I haven't had chance yet as I've been working on another project at thesametime.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to check if the cell has no color?  Why not just set the color for the whole range?

Comment: @FrankBall so some cells will already have a colour in them from the last time the sheet was updated and I don't want to overwrite that info so this way I am checking to make sure the cell is blank before changing the colour of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after a couple of iterations and some trial and error I have a solution.

```
Sub FILLGAPS()

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BP9:BP500")
If Range("BP" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BO9:BO500")
If Range("BO" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BN9:BN500")
If Range("BN" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BM9:BM500")
If Range("BM" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BL9:BL500")
If Range("BL" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BK9:BK500")
If Range("BK" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BJ9:BJ500")
If Range("BJ" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BI9:BI500")
If Range("BI" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BH9:BH500")
If Range("BH" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

For Each CELL In ActiveSheet.Range("BG9:BG500")
If Range("BG" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL
Next CELL

End Sub
```

big thanks to @FaneDuru for explaining the <> xlnone to me and for trying to make the code more streamlined

also thanks to @Notus_Panda for your contributions

Answer (score 0):

Please, play with the next code:

```
Sub testColorIndexNone()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, cel As Range, lastR As Long
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.Range("BG" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row ' last cell in BG:BG column
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("BG9:BG" & lastR)
  
  For Each cel In rng.cells
    If cel.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
        Debug.Print cel.address & " Color index: " & cel.Interior.ColorIndex
    Else
         cel.Interior.ColorIndex = cel.Offset(1).Interior.ColorIndex
         Debug.Print cel.address & " - no color"
    End If
  Next cel
End Sub
```

You may change the `rng` address as you need...

To see the output, please press `Ctrl + G`, being in VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor)...

**Edited**:

The next code will solve your problem in a little more elegant way:

```
Sub FILLGAPS()
 Dim cel As Range, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 Set rng = ws.Range("BG9:BP500")
 For Each cel In rng.cells
    If cel.address = "$BG$17" Then Stop
    If cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And _
            cel.Offset(1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
        cel.Interior.ColorIndex = cel.Offset(1).Interior.ColorIndex
        'cel.value = cel.Offset(1).value
    End If
 Next cel
End Sub
```

1. It is good to avoid using variables having a meaning for Excel VBA, even if not mandatory (cel instead of cell will not create any confusion)
2. Copying a cell over the other (even not containing anything) involves clipboard and this wastes Excel resources. **If the cell below the not colored one also contain a value and you want it being copied, please say that**. Now I assumed that this is what you want. If not, please comment the line `cel.value = cel.Offset(1).value`.

Comment: Think it's the next row, i.e. `.Offset(1)` that OP wants the "gap" to get

Comment: @Notus_Panda This is what I could understand from "**if BG15 is coloured then BG14 (if it is blank) needs to be the same colour as BG15**"... I understand that he needs the above cell interior color. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You're changing the `cel` 's color if it's got none and if it needs the next row (row 14 is empty -> same color as row 15), it should be `.Offset(1)` instead of -1 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: yes that is what I want @FaneDuru sorry just been working on another project so I am going to give this a try now and ill let you know if it works for me! thanks again.

Comment: @Notus_Panda So, if `cel` is not colored (BG14 which is blank - not colored ) should be colored as the above cell (BG15)... I maybe understand something wrong, but for me this logic looks being clear....

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi so when I try to run your code I get run time error 1004 application defined or object defined error and when I go into the debugger it highlights the set rng line. the only thing I changed on it was the range as I set it to BG9 to BG500. please can you walk me through what your code is trying to do as I am currently unsure. thanks

Comment: For row 14, row 13 is above, not row 15. Row 15 is the next in line (higher number) but if you look at it visually, it's below row 14. @Seb358 do you have it as `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("BG9:BG500")` ?

Comment: @Notus_Panda yes I do I also swapped the - to a positive number is the later part of the code as I think I understand what you are getting at

Comment: @Notus_Panda Ups... That „special understanding” was so clearly sticked to my brain... :) Yow were right, of course! Adapted the code. Thanks!

Comment: @FaneDuru so I realised I messed up when editing the range and typed BG00 instead of BG500 and now your code is working for me. my next challenge is how to fill in the cells that don't have a cell directly below them with colour in it. thanks again

Comment: @FaneDuru is there a way to make it so your code only looks at the BG column instead of the cell below? if that was possible I think that would be the solution so it would be cell offset 1 in the BG column. I'm gonna have a mess around myself but if you have any thoughts that would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Yes, but now I am driving...

Comment: @FaneDuru safe travels my friend :)

Comment: @Seb358  Please, test the updated code. But it will not fill all the range if two consecutive empty cells exists. It follows the logic of your question code. In such a case you must run the code twice. Or, if you clearly explain (in words) how do you like the code to behave, from this point of view, I can make it doing that...

Comment: @FaneDuru hi, I have tested the code you have supplied (thanks) and it fills in the cell labelled out so I have altered the range to be BG9:BP500 and this has had the effect of filling in the three cells above the three pinks, but I am trying to fill in BO13:BP13 and BG14:BP14 now I understand that filling in row 13 will probably need a second pass so we can forget about that for now, but do you have any suggestions on how to edit your code to fill in BG14:BP14 as I am unsure to how your current code works, again I appreciate your time and patience with me and my lack of understanding :)

Comment: @FaneDuru hi again, I think I might have figured it out. its a bit bulky and not as elegant as your code but I couldn't have done it without your comment about <> xlnone, I'm going to update my question with what I've put in place to solve it but if I can id like to give you the credit for answering it as you did originally answer my question about how to say anything but xlnone can I mark a comment as an answer? I'm new to stack overflow and I don't want to do anything that the mods might not like please let me know.

Comment: @Seb358 You cannot mark a comment as answer. Only an answer as accepted one... I looked to the updated question and I will maybe help you solving he whole problem, but I am not sure that I understand what you try doing. What do you expect from `ActiveSheet.Range("BG" & CELL.Row + 1).Copy CELL`? Not changing the interior color with the one above, if it is not colored? If so, I will adapt/simplify the above code to do it in a simpler way.

Comment: @Seb358 Please, check the code I pasted after **Edited**. And answer the clarification question related to what is to be copied. **Does the colored non empty cell below also contain a value and you want it being copied**?

Comment: @FaneDuru so if you look back to the data pic I posted in the question. the sheet gets updated and this time has left a gap. the gap starts at BO13 and finishes at BP14 (the range is contained within BG9:BP500) therefore all cells in row 14 and 13 need to be coloured. but I only want to colour blank cells. therefore I need all of row 14 (between BG and BP filling in) as the same colour as BG15 as well as BO13:BP13. also no there is no value in the cells they are only coloured in I use that copy method as it is the fastest one I know (was given to me in another question I asked recently)

Comment: @Seb358 Did you test the updated code? Please, refresh the page (this one), copy the code after **edited** and run it.  In the picture I can see, only the empty cells in row 14, first three columns have to be updated with the color of row 15. Isn't it what you want? At least, this is what your large code does! So, if **in the first column it is an empty cell (BG14) and below it a colored one (BG15), do you want all that empty row to be colored as the one below**? This also means that **the whole row itself (15)** should be colored as the first cell.

Comment: @Seb358 Did ou say anything about that coloring of the whole row (somewhere) and I missed it?

Comment: @FaneDuru I guess on my main question it doesn't specify that I mean everything before the latest BG column so that my bad but there was a comment I added this morning which specified it better. and the large code I posted fills in all of row 14 based off the colour of BG15 but no I don't want 15 to be coloured in as well. so these boxes are a percentage. every cell from BG to BP is worth 10% so when the data is reported back it is turned into a percentage and then that percentage is expressed as a number of cells coloured in. therefore, on Wednesday the line achieved 30% of row 15 so 3 cells

Comment: @Seb358  I keep reading your last comment and I am completely confused. I mean, I cannot find a sense of "I need all of row 14 (between BG and BP filling in) as the same colour as BG15 **as well as BO13:BP13**". What color to be applied on "BO13:BP13" and based on what? There is no color below this mentioned range. And to be even stranger, first cell of row 13 is colored in a kind of orange and the next 7 cells in red... I am afraid that I am  not a mind reader and I cannot help if you do not clearly explain what you need...

Comment: @FaneDuru are coloured in, on Tuesday the line completed 80% of row 13 so 8 of the cells are coloured in, since the numbers I am given are finishing numbers that means on Wednesday the line must have also completed the last 20% of row 13 as well as 100% of row 14 therefore, if I have a macro that looks for coloured cells in the BG column that have blank cells 'above it' then the macro can fill them in. and when I say above it I don't just mean directly above I mean anywhere north of the coloured BG that is blank between BG and BP I hope this makes more sense to you (btw thecodeIpostedisworking

Comment: @FaneDuru I might just answer this with the second lot of code I posted in my question as that is working for me at the moment I would like to give you the credit though as it was you that said about the <>xlnone thing that helped me to get it working.

Comment: @Seb358 theoretically, the more compact code I posted should exactly do what your large code does. But none of them will fill all the row based on value in BG column. You are talking about percentages and week days which are abstract in the context of your question. I am afraid I cannot help you more, since I cannot understand what you say. And no credit is needed.

Comment: @FaneDuru the code I posted does work and fills in the full row based on the BG column  that is what I am trying to tell you, that it works. it fills in all of row 14 based on BG15. thankyou for your help on this, I was stuck on the whole <> xlnone thing and I appreciate the time you spent trying to make the code more elegant and work quicker.

Answer (score -2):

There is no such thing as `xlNone` when it's interior color.
What you have is a numeric value of the color, sadly white and "no color" is the same value `16777215`

So

```
If Range("BG" & CELL.Row).Interior.Color <> 16777215 then
```

is true if there is no color or white, which to most people is the same.

EDIT:

I just realized there is a way.
If you use `.colorindex` then no color is `-4142` and white is `2`.

```
If Range("BG" & CELL.Row).Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 then
```

Means there is no color, not even white.

I also now realized I used colorindex in the code previous codeblock but meant color.

This sub works perfectly fine. If the color is nothing then it prints nothing.
If it's white or any other color then it prints the colorindex of the cell BG1.
I hardcoded it to BG1 to make sure it's not `CELL` that is the issue

```
Sub test2()
    If Range("BG" & 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then
        Debug.Print Range("BG" & 1).Interior.ColorIndex
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thanks i will give this a go and let you know if it works however in my experience (which is very limited) xlnone has been working fine for me until now as I have other bits of code which check if a cell has colour before changing the colour. unless xlnone is situational? either way thankyou and ill get back to you :)

Comment: hi @andreas I've just tried this but its come up with the same compile error I got with xlnone, do I have to put values inside the more than less than signs? (the error says compile error: expected:expression) thanks again :)

Comment: @chrisneilsen So editing the answer is not an option? Why would there be an edit button then? And please when you write incorrect words like `respo6is` make sure you delete your comment instead.

Comment: @Seb358 See my newly added sub in the answer. This code works fine. Are you sure `CELL` is set when you run the code?

Comment: An edit is fine if you kept the correct stuff/Put at the top of your original thought that it's wrong. As it is now, you're still having "does not exist" (which is wrong, I tested it) at the top which people may just remember as is.

Comment: Well if the person is specifically using `ColorIndex` and then you start saying that Color doesn't have xlNone, then that just proves my point. I read what you said as "don't use xlNone because it's not a valid value for it", that's how easy it goes (my apologies for mis-reading it). So don't feel "attacked", no one is crying, we just don't want people to get the wrong info. You could just add "(but ColorIndex does have it)" and/or "or xlNone" with the "-4142" and there would already be less confusion. We're here to help people/each other :)

Comment: I have read your full answer, below and above the EDIT, but I stand with what I said. As you can't seem to stick with reason and OP has now two possible solutions (one of which is yours that I did not downvote btw), I'll just move on from this. Hope you can find your calm again.